# Cluster analysis with nominal, ordinal and metric data

Tags: cluster-analysis, scale, mixed

I got a data set wit *nominal*, *ordinal* **and** *metric* variables. 
I want to perform a cluster analysis, 
since I have mixed scales it seems that using k-modes clustering is the most appropriate way to explore the data.
Or has anyone a better way in mind? I am thanksful for any advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to just make there program run.

It needs to answer the right question. K-means, k-medians, k-medoids, k-modes. Each optimizes a different function. Math won't tell you which function it the best for you. That is the question you need to answer, which function solves your problem?

Comment: Maybe this is the question (which underlines that I am new in this field): what problem do I want to get solved? By now I want to figure out consumer groups depending on one variable. 
K-means can't be a solution, since I want to use all kind of variables in the cluster analsysis.By now I got the impression, k median fits esepcially with ordinal data; whereas k mode seems to be the best way with nominal data. So do I count if I have more nominal or ordinal variables and decide than for one method? Or do i use both methods to valid each other?

Comment: You are looking at the technical side. Stop this. Start looking at the logic: what is *good for your problem*. Don't use k modes just because it is the only thing you can find that is able to handle nominal variables. That does not mean it does anything useful. How do you know the result is better than random? First, you really need to **understand and formalize your problem**, rather than trying random algorithms. If *you* don't know what to do, how is the algorithm going to do the right thing when there are billions of bad answers?

Comment: @Papea, your missing the point raised earlier by @Anony-Mousse. The point is, the family of `k-means` algorithms (like `k-means`, `k-medoids`, `k-median`) will cluster or group the data irrespective of whether groups exist or not. In my opinion, for a clustering problem, its imperative to first determine whether there exist patterns or not. For this, in literature there exists methods like, "elbow", or a "scree plot".

Comment: That is part of it: the methods *can* easily make false discoveries when used wrong. But the elbow and scree plots won't protect you from that entirely. If you use the wrong tool, the answer will be useless. And wrong is not technical: there will be multiple algorithms that can be used, but that will give contradicting results (even with good elbow or scree). The *only* way to choose the right algorithm is to spell out the math assumptions you make, and how this is optimized by one algorithm (right tool) and not the other (wrong tool). The assumptions are dataset specific.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: thank you so much for your advices! I try to consider your advice, but it's still hard. When I have a look on my data, I am pretty sure the ordinal as well as the metric variables will have a stronger effect on the clustering groups in comparison to the nominal variables. Is this now the beginning of looking at the logcial side?:)

Comment: @Ashish: thank you very much as well! If I respect from now on more the logical side for choosing an algorithm, using a "scree plot" seems to be an additional step to underly my statistical proceeding?